# Im try send data from client to server and i get error

Tags: python, reactjs, django, windows, web

Im try send data from client to server and i get errorm, i use django, python & react.

name: 'AxiosError'
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

message: "Unsupported protocol localhost:"

the error i have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlDcq.png)
the data i want to send
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o3ud.png)
api
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbzAb.png)
views
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MhsT.png)
url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz75b.png)
models
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPHJp.png)

```
   data i want to send


    const onPay = () => {
    service.PurchaseDetailsService.setPurchaseDetails(
      100,
      "test",
      "test1",
      3,
      4,
      52
    );
    };

     api
    import Axios from "axios";
    const $axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "localhost:8000/api/",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
    });
    $axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {
    console.error("got error");
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
    }
    );
    class PurchaseDetailsService {
     static setPurchaseDetails(id, items, name, price, 
     cardNumber, 
     idOfPerson) {
     const bodyFormData = new FormData();
     bodyFormData.append("id", id);
     bodyFormData.append("items", items);
     bodyFormData.append("name", name);
     bodyFormData.append("price", price);
     bodyFormData.append("cardNumber", cardNumber);
     bodyFormData.append("idOfPerson", idOfPerson);
     return $axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `PurchaseDetails/get_mock_PurchaseDetails/${id}`,
      data: bodyFormData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
      });
      }  
     }
     const service = {
     PurchaseDetailsService,
    };

    export default service;

    views
     
      from rest_framework import status
      from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, 
      renderer_classes
      from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
      from rest_framework.response import Response
      from myStore.serializers import PurchaseDetailsSerializer
      from myStore.models import PurchaseDetails
      from myStore.serializers import PurchaseDetails


     @api_view(['GET'])
     @renderer_classes([JSONRenderer])
     def get_PurchaseDetails(_, PurchaseDetails):
        PurchaseDetails = get_mock_PurchaseDetails()
       serializer = PurchaseDetailsSerializer(PurchaseDetails)

       return Response(serializer.data, 
    status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


      def get_mock_PurchaseDetails(id, items,
                             name,   price,   cardNumber, 
       idOfPerson):
       newData = PurchaseDetails(id,items, name,
                              price, cardNumber, idOfPerson)

       newData.save()


    url 

    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('api/PurchaseDetails/get_mock_PurchaseDetails/<int:id>',
         views.get_mock_PurchaseDetails),
    ]



    models

    from django.db import models

    class PurchaseDetails(models.Model):
      id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      items = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      price = models.IntegerField()
      cardNumber = models.IntegerField()
      idOfPerson = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Ok, now please post your code as formatted text and your errors as formatted text

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the url to const `baseURL='http://localhost:8000/api/'`

Comment: its still not working

Comment: Try `baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api` without "/" tell me if it work

Comment: its not working

Comment: Are you getting a different error?

Comment: yes , now i have this message message: "Network Error", and this error net::ERR_FAILED 403, and this error : Order:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/api/PurchaseDetails/get_mock_PurchaseDetails/100' from origin 'localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. –

Comment: OK first thing try this line of code : `const $axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "/api/",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});`

Comment: Then for second error I think It looks like the issue is with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). CORS is a security feature that prevents a web page from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the page. In this case, it appears that your React application is running on "localhost:3000" and trying to make a request to "localhost:8000", which are considered different domains. Install `pip install django-cors-headers`

Comment: its still not working, message:"Request failed with status code 403"